# Php string concatenating variables with forward slash

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to create a unique id by concatenating 3 variables using forward slashes(/). my code is like so

```
$year . "/" . $acronym . "/" . $num;
```

I am expecting an output of

```
"18/MC/1"
```

but the output I get is

```
"18\/MC\/1"
```

What am I doing wrong. I have already tried using `stripslashes()` but it doesn't do anything to the output.

Comment: can you put your code was make the output ?

Comment: Could it be that $year and $acronym have the backward slashes in it's own strings?

Comment: dd() function giving me expected output "18/MC/1", please print your variables seperately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong,
The code below outputs the correct format `18/MC/1`

`return response()->json([$id]);`

while my previous code was

`return response()->json($id);`

which gave me an output of

`"18/MC/1"

Answer (score 0):

You could use `join` function

```
<?php 
// ...
join([$year, $acronym, $num], '/');
```

For more info, see: [Join function documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php)

Answer (score -1):

There is function in php to remove backward slash from string use following function.

echo stripslashes(string);

output: 18/MC/1